# XML Element with prefix read issue in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I need to get a specific xml element value.
Here is the xml code I have

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:hdr="http://www.example.com/hdr/">
<soapenv:Header>
<hdr:ERROR_CODE>0</hdr:ERROR_CODE>
<hdr:ERROR_DESC>Success</hdr:ERROR_DESC>
<hdr:ASYNCH_RESPONSE_INDICATOR>0</hdr:ASYNCH_RESPONSE_INDICATOR>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body><CREATE_RESPONSE></CREATE_RESPONSE>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is the way I tried

```
var response = @"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:hdr='http://www.example.com/hdr/'>
                        <soapenv:Header>
<hdr:ERROR_CODE>0</hdr:ERROR_CODE>
<hdr:ERROR_DESC>Success</hdr:ERROR_DESC>
<hdr:ASYNCH_RESPONSE_INDICATOR>0</hdr:ASYNCH_RESPONSE_INDICATOR>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body><CREATE_RETAILER_RESPONSE></CREATE_RETAILER_RESPONSE>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>";
        var responseXdoc = XDocument.Parse(response);
        var nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
        nsManager.AddNamespace("hdr", "http://www.example.com/hdr");
        var statusElement = responseXdoc.XPathSelectElement("//hdr:ERROR_CODE", nsManager);
        
        Console.WriteLine(statusElement.Value);
```

It's returning this error

```
[System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   at Program.Main() :line 26
```

Here is [dotnet fiddler url](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3F5or3)

What can be the issue?

Comment: In your fiddle i've found an error in namespace name! See: [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7bJX5L)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could select the element using Linq's [FirstOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-5.0)

```
var statusElement = responseXdoc.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName == "ERROR_CODE");
```